# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS no audio input device found

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04

On my fresh Ubuntu22.04 LTS installation, the microphone was not detected.
It works fine on Windows11 on the same machine
Is there a driver available for this?

This is output from alsa-info
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0858447b5d901f4789d24976d7e22ad3695c4c92

[image: Hardware]

[image: settings]

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`:

```
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8b2f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
03:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 6f)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [103c:8b2f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp6x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
03:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [103c:8b2f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1505]
```

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `arecord -l` ; pactl list sources short

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `aplay -l` . Did you add any modprobe or GRUB options to disable DMIC? Have you explored `hdajackretask`?

Comment: $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: I did nothing to GRUB. I just installed hdajackretask and am trying to figure out what it does.

Comment: You can try HWE with `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` . Some people on mint forums said updates worked. Please also [edit] with `arecord -l ; pactl list sources short`

Comment: linux-generic-hwe-22.04 was already installed

Comment: $ arecord -l ; pactl list sources short
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED
1 alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz IDLE

Comment: Try `pactl load-module module-alsa-source`. I'm not sure yet which other arguments to pass to the right of that command

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I also connected an external microphone through the audio jack but Ubuntu seems to think it is headphones!

Comment: Try `fn+f8`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HP_255_G10

Comment: fn+f8 is a microphone mute key. The problem is that the OS is not recognizing the input device. I tried it anyway but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: This is output from alsa-info http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0858447b5d901f4789d24976d7e22ad3695c4c92

Comment: Daniel T, can you post an answer so that I can award you the bounty. Although my problem still persists, you were the one who tried to help me the most. Thanks BTW I posted output from also-info.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled pipewire and the built-in audio option started showing :-

```
sudo apt reinstall pipewire pipewire-bin pipewire-pulse
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did nothing for me. Thank you for your input.